# Partial dynamic mapping in elastic search from java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to disable dynamic mapping for date datatype and have to add specific mapping for date datatype in elasticsearch. For that

I am using code :

```
     CreateIndexResponse indexRequestBuilder = transportClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate(index_name).setSettings(
                        settings).addMapping(index_name, createMappingBuilder(index_name)).execute().actionGet();

        private static XContentBuilder createMappingBuilder(String typeName)
                  throws IOException
          {
            XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject(typeName).
    startObject("mappings").startObject(typeName).field("dynamic_date_formats","[\"dd/MM/yyyy\"]")
.endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject();

            return builder;
          }
```

After runing this code I am getting exception :

> MapperParsingException[Root mapping definition has unsupported
>   parameters:  [mappings :
>   {index_name={dynamic_date_formats=["dd/MM/yyyy"]}}]];

Elastic version :2.4

Any update will be helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I got out of the issue by removing the root level from json. Code fragment change is :     I changed the code to                                                        
       XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder()
            .startObject().startObject(typeName).field("dynamic_date_formats","dd/MM/yyyy").endObject().endObject();   but this raised an issue. Earlier as soon as I was persisting the data into elastic, I was able to query on that data. But above change, I am getting search results after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved as specified in comment and another issue which I mentioned in comment got resolved by refreshindex call